# Vai haver ou vão haver?

Tags: verbos, composições

Em Portugal usamos muito o tempo composto para indicar o futuro, por exemplo:

> Amanhã vou comer bife.

em vez de

> Amanhã comerei bife.

Mas, na substituição do verbo haver, há uma dúvida que surge constantemente que é se usamos **vai haver** ou **vão haver**, exemplo:

> Amanhã vai/vão haver aulas?

A confusão existe por causa das aulas que estão no plural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando um verbo impessoal é conjugado com um auxiliar, o auxiliar mantém a invariância do verbo principal (como você pode, por exemplo, consultar [aqui](http://vestibular.uol.com.br/ultnot/resumos/ult2772u40.jhtm)). Como "haver" nesse sentido é impessoal, devemos dizer:

> Amanhã vai haver aulas.

Answer (score 3):

*Amanhã vão haver aulas?* é apenas possível se *haver* significar *ter*, o que é incomum, especialmente no Brasil, i.e, se equivaler a *amanhã (os alunos) vão ter aulas*.

E mesmo em Portugal, tenho a ideia de que, fora da literatura, o uso de "haver" como verbo pleno não impessoal, além de ser formal, é mais usado para significar "considerar" ("havido por/como irrelevante", "houveram por bem").

Já agora, um aparte: *amanhã vou comer bife* e *amanhão comerei bife* não são em geral equivalentes. A primeira impressão de *vou comer bife* é que se vai a algum lado comer bife, e não apenas que se come bife (claro que em contexto podem ser equivalentes). Mais perto de *comerei bife* estará *amanhã como bife*.

Comment: Esse aparte não parece verdade, para Portugal. `Amanhã vou comer bife` não implica ir a lado nenhum: "- És vegetariano? Vejo-te sempre almoçar saladas e legumadas... - Não! É coincidência, logo vou comer bife."

Comment: @ANeves Dado o contexto certo, não (como concedi entre parênteses), referia-me apenas à primeira impressão ao ver a frase isolada. Compara: "não te preocupes, amanhã compro/comprarei/hei de comprar isso" com "não te preocupes, amanhã vou comprar isso". Se fosses comprar o produto online, sem sair de casa, provavelmente não usarias "vou".

Comment: Usaria sim. "Vou comprar" estaria certo. Por ordem decrescente de hábito, usaria: compro; vou comprar; hei-de comprar; comprarei. Se calhar estou a usar mal, mas é a vida...

Comment: @ANeves Não diria mal, parece simplesmente que a construção perifrástica com ir está mais gramaticalizada contigo.

Comment: @Artefacto com ele e com muita gente. Ao que parece a utilização de do futuro "haverá" está a decair em relação a utilização do futuro composto "vai haver".